# Execute mongsh from shell with clean output?

Tags: mongodb

I have a file containing a mongodb query. I want to execute it in my shell and get the output back to the shell. Currenlty, I cannot do that without also getting a lot of bloated connection info and such. Is this possible in any way?

What I am currently doing is: `mongosh --quiet [db URL] < myscriptfile.js`

Answer (score 0):

Try `mongosh --quiet [db URL] myscriptfile.js`.

Or better use the classic `mongo` shell!

I know, classic `mongo` shell is deprecated, however new `mongosh` is still *very* beta-state and far away from being a usable successor for classic `mongo` shell.